# Do higher priority SCHED_RR real-time tasks completely starve all lower priority tasks if there are enough of them?

Tags: posix, scheduling, real-time

I'm reading through the man page for scheduling and the description for the round-robin real-time scheduling policy seems ambiguous to me:

```
   SCHED_RR: Round-robin scheduling
       SCHED_RR is a simple enhancement of SCHED_FIFO.  Everything
       described above for SCHED_FIFO also applies to SCHED_RR, except
       that each thread is allowed to run only for a maximum time
       quantum.  If a SCHED_RR thread has been running for a time period
       equal to or longer than the time quantum, it will be put at the
       end of the list for its priority.  A SCHED_RR thread that has
       been preempted by a higher priority thread and subsequently
       resumes execution as a running thread will complete the unexpired
       portion of its round-robin time quantum.  The length of the time
       quantum can be retrieved using sched_rr_get_interval(2).
```

Is there any guarantee that tasks of a lower RT priority will ever run?  Or does this literally mean that the scheduler will start at priority 99 and round robin through the tasks at each priority level only proceeding to the lower levels if there's time left over after the higher priorities have expended their quantum/blocked?

Comment: RT (Real Time) tasks run until the task decides not to, or encounters a blocking SYSCALL. That's part of the definition. A single RT task, say, "count from 1 to 10 by 0", could "starve" ALL other tasks.

Comment: That's SCHED_FIFO.  If you have multiple tasks from SCHED_RR at the same priority they should share equally.  I just want to know if they tend to leave crumbs.  Also in my specific case on most recent linux systems there's 5% of CPU time reserved for normal tasks by default so you can log in and kill the endless loop.